# Get average of first index for each element in list using C#

Tags: c#, json, average

Right now I have a list of `DataPointSet`

```
public class DataPointSet {
    public string target{ get; set; }
    public List<List<decimal>>  datapoints{ get; set; }
}
```

I append `DataPointSet` to a list using a foreach loop.

Now, within that list... is there a way I can get the average of every `datapoints` list but only for the first `0` index?

The list of objects gets output as json in the end and I'll use that to explain what I'm going for:

```
[
  {
    "target": "target_one",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        8.0,
        1493510400.0
      ],
      [
        8.0,
        1493596800.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "target_two",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        1.0,
        1493510400.0
      ],
      [
        1.0,
        1493596800.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1493683200.0
      ]
    ]
  },
]
```

For each one of the elements in the list/json, I want to get the average of all the first elements in the `datapoints` key.

Is there a simple way built into c# that I can use to do this or is my only option looping through each element and then comparing?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the SUM(DataPointSet1.DataPoints[0] + DataPointSet2.DataPoints[0].... + DataPointSetN.DataPoints[0]) / N ??

Comment: `decimal average = data.datapoints.Select(element => element.First()).Average();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you have simple way with LINQ.

So, you have:

```
List<DataPointSet> dataPointSets = ...;
```

Then, you can find the answer with this code:

```
foreach (var dataPointSet in dataPointSets)
{
    var average = dataPointSet.datapoints
       .Average(innerList => innerList.First())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for LINQ. You could make it quick and dirty, if you know that the nested lists always have elements. Thanks to @JoePhillips for some corrections.

```
list
    .SelectMany(x => x.datapoints)
    .Average(x => x.First());
```

Note that this query is getting the average of 8.0, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0, and 10.0.

Comment: I believe `SelectMany()` would improve this a bit more

Comment: @JoePhillips updated to include your suggestion. It also revealed an issue with my initial logic. Should I remove the original solution from my post? See update.

Comment: `list.SelectMany(x => x.datapoints.First()).Average(x => x)` might also be an improvement. Not sure if it's the same though. Only remove the initial solution if it is wrong

Comment: I may have led you astray. SelectMany probably doesn't work here :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Linq Average method on your list.

```
using System.Linq;

List<decimal> firsts =  datapoints.ForEach(i=>i.First());
firsts.Average();
```

Comment: But would this do it for the first element index in each datapoint set only? The second is a timestamp and should not be averaged.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, didn't realize you had a list of lists and stuff. I updated to get the first item from each List and assign it to it's own list. Then average that list.